# how to use an abbreviation for a title

Tags: differences

How do I show that I want to note that it is going to be SSN for Social Security Administration later in my paragraph? We use the Social Security Administration (SSN) or ("SSN") for many things.  The SSN is very helpful.

Comment: *SSN* stands for a lot of things, but *Social Security **A**dministration* is not one of them. In the context of Social Security it stands for *Social Security **N**umber*

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on your style guide.

APA style is described in [this blog post](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/abbreviations/#Q2):

> When the spelled-out version first appears in the narrative of the sentence, put the abbreviation in parentheses after it:
>
> Example: We studied attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder (ADHD) in children.
>
> [...]
>
> After you define an abbreviation [...] use only the abbreviation. Do not alternate between spelling out the term and abbreviating it.

Other style guides recommend essentially the same thing (e.g. the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch10/ch10_sec003.html)), but you should check your style guide to see what it says. (And if you're not using any style guide, then you can follow any style guide you want).